# What is run when a program offers you to open a file in Linux?

Tags: file-manager

There are several programs that give the option for the user to open a file on their computer (text editors are a common example). This opens a window allowing me to find the file I want to select. Typically, it uses my default file manager. However, there are some programs that load a completely different-looking file manager that is definitely not Nautilus (I use Nemo, which is a fork of Nautilus for Cinnamon). So my questions are:

1. What is run when I choose to open a file from one of these programs?
2. How can I ensure that the same file manager is used across all programs when I try to open a file?

On a side note, the specific program I have in mind that loads a completely different file manager is just a Java program I downloaded from www.nand2tetris.org/software.php for a course. It is not any package provided by any repository. I am not sure if that may be the reason as to why this problem is occurring, but I think it is important to include.

I'm sorry if this question is bad or hard to understand, it is fairly difficult to word. If I am missing any details, please tell me, and I will add it.

Comment: Are you really talking about a file manager (a program that lets you browse directories, copy files, etc.), or about a file opening dialog (something that lets you select a file by browsing directories, and once you've selected the file and clicked “OK” the window goes away)?